# How can I know what element is currently selected in a column of a multi-column-ion-picker, if it hasn't been confirmed yet?

Tags: ionic4

The thing is, I made an ion-picker with 2 columns. In the first column there are only 2 options to choose from and depending on what is currently selected in that column, the second column's values should change. So my question is, how can I find out what is currently selected in the first column, if I can't confirm it?

The second column should get it's information from an array with values in it.
And please don't criticize me for the variable-names in the code below, I'm probably going to change them later on.

```
async showMultiColumnPicker(id) {
    if (this.disabledis[id - 6] !== true) {
    const opts: PickerOptions = {
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'Done',
          role: 'confirm',
          handler: async () => {
            const vari1 = await      
                  this.picker_cancer.getColumn(this.pickerbois[id].name);
            const vari2 = await this.picker_cancer.getColumn('2nd row');
            this.selectedvalue = vari1.options[vari1.selectedIndex].text +
            ' ' + vari2.options[vari2.selectedIndex].text;
            this.selected[id] = this.selectedvalue;
          }
        }
      ],
      columns: [
        {     //1st row
          name: this.pickerbois[id].name,
          options:  this.pickerbois[id].options[0]
        },
        {     // How can you know which option is 
              // currently selected in the first column?
          name: '2nd row',
          options: this.pickerbois[id].options[1]
        //options: this.pickerbois[id].options[2] in case of the second          
        //attribute in the 1st row being selected
        }
      ]
    };
    const picker = await this.pickerCtrl.create(opts);
    this.picker_cancer = picker;
    picker.present();
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I figured that the Date Time Picker did it for the days of the month so it must be possible.

Digging around in the code is a great way to answer your questions, and [in the datetime.tsx](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/datetime/datetime.tsx#L262) file I found this:

```
picker.addEventListener('ionPickerColChange', async (event: any) => {
  const data = event.detail;

  const colSelectedIndex = data.selectedIndex;
  const colOptions = data.options;

  const changeData: any = {};
  changeData[data.name] = {
    value: colOptions[colSelectedIndex].value
  };

  this.updateDatetimeValue(changeData);
  picker.columns = this.generateColumns();
});
```

A top secret event that you can handle which solves your problem!

I thought that it was a mistake in the documentation, but it seems from [more digging around](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/18216) with this new information, `ionPickerColChange` is marked `@internal`.

That means it could change in the future and isn't officially supported.

It seems that maybe there are some display issues in some scenarios that could be preventing them from making this part of the public api, so see how you get on, and good luck!

One final thing I noticed during my research, [this forum thread](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-v4-pickercontroller-that-changes-its-columns-based-on-selection/161422) has a `forceUpdate` call at the end:

```
picker.forceUpdate();
```

If you have trouble, try that.

Comment: Your answer worked partly for me so I'm thankful for that, but 2 new issues came up. The first is that I can't distinguish which column is being targeted by this and the second is that it doesn't update the visible data of the second col. It updates the values that are used in the background, but not the visible values. Any idea on that?

Comment: I haven't actually implemented this myself, I just tried to research it for you when it came up. Did you try the `forceUpdate()` tip I put at the end? Have you set an id or class on the columns that you could detect perhaps? Or maybe look in the tsx I linked to for more inspiration about how they track the columns. I guess this is maybe why its not a public api.

Comment: I now found a way around the 'not being able to distinguish the columns problem', but the values still don't update for some reason. forceUpdate() didn't help me with my issue, in fact I didn't notice any difference with/without it. But still, thank you for your help.